# Optimize AEM QueryBuilder with facets

Tags: extjs, aem, query-builder, jcr

The asset data is around 5000 records and increasing.

The query being used to paint the search page is similar to following.

`querybuilder.json?
0_group.property=jcr:content/metadata/cq:tags&
0_group.property.and=true
&0_group.property.value=something:facets/element-type/images`

The above is providing search by certain other arguments within 0.5sec.

But if `p.facets=true` is used in the query, it would cross 13seconds to respond.

How this can be optimized to keep the response under 5 seconds ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to add or modify an index for the property you are searching.

This article outlines useful troubleshooting techniques: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/troubleshooting-slow-queries.html

> There are 3 main classifications of slow queries in AEM, listed by
>   severity:
>
> 1. Index-less queries
>          Queries that do not resolve to an index and traverse the JCR's contents to collect results
> 2. Poorly restricted (or scoped) queries
>          Queries that resolve to an index, but must traverse all index entries to collect results
> 3. Large result set queries
>          Queries that return very large numbers of results

Additional info:

- http://www.cqtutorial.com/courses/cq-admin/cq-admin-lessons/cq-performance-tuning/cq-search-performance-tuning
- https://adapt.to/content/dam/adaptto/production/presentations/2017/adaptTo2017-Optimizing-Oak-Repository-Search-Olaf-Jentsch.pdf/_jcr_content/renditions/original.media_file.download_attachment.file/adaptTo2017-Optimizing-Oak-Repository-Search-Olaf-Jentsch.pdf